# How do I count based on different rows conditions in PySpark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following Dataframe:

| ID | Payment | Value | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Cash | 200 | 2020-01-01 |
| 1 | Credit Card | 500 | 2020-01-06 |
| 2 | Cash | 300 | 2020-02-01 |
| 3 | Credit Card | 400 | 2020-02-02 |
| 3 | Credit Card | 500 | 2020-01-03 |
| 3 | Cash | 200 | 2020-01-04 |

What I'd like to do is to count how many ID's have used both Cash and Credit Card.

For example, in this case there would be 2 ID's that used both Cash and Credit Card.

How would I do that on PySpark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`collect_set`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.collect_set) to count how many payment methods each user has.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

(df
    .groupBy('ID')
    .agg(F.collect_set('Payment').alias('methods'))
    .withColumn('methods_size', F.size('methods'))
    .show()
)

# +---+-------------------+------------+
# | ID|            methods|methods_size|
# +---+-------------------+------------+
# |  1|[Credit Card, Cash]|           2|
# |  3|[Credit Card, Cash]|           2|
# |  2|             [Cash]|           1|
# +---+-------------------+------------+
```